# vuejs-datepicker Nuxt issue

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use `vuejs-datepicker` with Nuxt (version: 2.15.8). I've followed the steps written in [this documentation](https://www.aslamdoctor.com/using-vuejs-datepicker-with-nuxt-js/).

Everything worked fine but when I tried to import the translation to the component, I've got the following error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'.
> 'd:/projectname/node_modules/vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale/index.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.

I've imported it this way:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { es } from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale';
import { computed, defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
...
```

The plugins/vue-datepicker.js code is the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'    
Vue.component('date-picker', Datepicker)
```

And the nuxt.config.js :

```
...
plugins: [{
        src: '~/plugins/vue-datepicker',
        ssr: false
    }, ],
...
```

What is the proper way to import the translation?